# Android black-screen & crash after starting an intent

Tags: android, xml, crash, camera, screen

i have a little problem with the app im trying to develop.
It's just a little camera-app.

That's what i want to do:
...take a picture and save it. Start another activity, load the picture in a pictureview (therfore i save the pictures path, so i could load/create a bmp by using BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picutrepath))...

But that doesn't work.
The screen turns black, and it is not even loading the xml.
I always get a System.out saying "not a drm file opening notmally" but i don't know wether it is related to my try of loading the picture via BitmapFactory.
I used Log.i to see if something is wrong with the path im using, but everything is fine.
So i decided to try if i could load a simple .png-image from my R.drawables,
but that doesn't work as well.
The curious thing is that after the screen turns black the app just quits/exits without errors.

Hope someone can help me, thanks :)

Here's the code:

How i start my second activity:

```
.
.
.
takepictureButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cameralayout_takepictureButton);
        takepictureButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpgCallback);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i("", "Starting INTENT");
                intentstart();

            }
        });
.
.
.
private void intentstart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FacebarActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
.
.
.
```

Activity that i want to start:

```
public class FacebarActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imageview;
    private ImageButton cButton, xButton;
    private Bitmap picture;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pictureview);

    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pictureviewLayout_pictureView);

    picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.buttonplay);
    imageview.setImageBitmap(picture);

    cButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pictureviewLayout_CButton);
    cButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    XButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pictureviewLayout_XButton);
    XButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    startthis();

}
```

And the pictureview.xml that i load with setContentView() :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".CameraActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/pictureviewLayout_topbarlinearlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/topbar" >
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pictureviewLayout_pictureView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/pictureviewLayout_bottombarlinearlayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pictureviewLayout_topbarlinearlayout" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/pictureviewLayout_bottombarlinearlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bottombar" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pictureviewLayout_CButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pictureviewLayout_XButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pictureviewLayout_XButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pictureviewLayout_CButton"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_clear_all" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the logcat:

```
01-23 20:47:00.995: D/dalvikvm(7776): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 69K, 6% free 12160K/12931K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
01-23 20:47:00.995: I/dalvikvm-heap(7776): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.841MB for 432016-byte allocation
01-23 20:47:01.020: D/dalvikvm(7776): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 12581K/13383K, paused 12ms+1ms, total 25ms
01-23 20:47:01.055: D/dalvikvm(7776): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 12581K/13383K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
01-23 20:47:01.055: I/dalvikvm-heap(7776): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.573MB for 768016-byte allocation
01-23 20:47:01.085: D/dalvikvm(7776): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 6% free 13331K/14151K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 27ms
01-23 20:47:01.085: D/dalvikvm(7776): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
01-23 20:47:01.105: D/dalvikvm(7776): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 424K, 9% free 12913K/14151K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
01-23 20:47:01.120: D/dalvikvm(7776): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 13335K/14151K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 18ms
01-23 20:47:01.120: D/dalvikvm(7776): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 2ms
01-23 20:47:01.140: D/dalvikvm(7776): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 13335K/14151K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
01-23 20:47:01.145: I/dalvikvm-heap(7776): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.309MB for 768016-byte allocation
01-23 20:47:01.160: D/dalvikvm(7776): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 6% free 14085K/14919K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 19ms
01-23 20:47:01.330: D/libEGL(7776): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-23 20:47:01.355: D/libEGL(7776): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-23 20:47:01.355: D/libEGL(7776): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-23 20:47:01.380: D/(7776): Device driver API match
01-23 20:47:01.380: D/(7776): Device driver API version: 10
01-23 20:47:01.380: D/(7776): User space API version: 10 
01-23 20:47:01.380: D/(7776): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
01-23 20:47:01.440: D/OpenGLRenderer(7776): Enabling debug mode 0
01-23 20:47:02.040: I/Choreographer(7776): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-23 20:47:09.230: I/APPLICATION(7776): STARTIng INTENT
01-23 20:47:09.235: I/Kurz bevor(7776): null
01-23 20:47:09.290: I/APPLICATION(7776): STARTED INTENT
01-23 20:47:09.290: I/Choreographer(7776): Skipped 308 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-23 20:47:09.605: D/dalvikvm(7776): GC_CONCURRENT freed 836K, 10% free 13905K/15367K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 12ms
01-23 20:47:09.605: D/dalvikvm(7776): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
```

Comment: edited and added the logcat, hope that helps

Comment: You should learn how to debug using eclipse so you can step through your code in order to find exactly where the problem occurs.. The logcat you posted really isn't helpful . There isn't any stack trace from a crash in it.

Comment: First off, the title of your question states "crash" -- there is no crash in the logcat. Secondly, I see a lot of skipped frames, which, as logcat explains, comes from doing too much work on the UI thread. If you're trying to encode or resize a bitmap on the UI thread, it would be expected that you see a black screen and likely an ANR. Long-running operations need to run off the UI thread.